# Deploying error in different Operating System - vb6

Tags: vb6

This Application was coded in win 11 OS. The app was deployed successfully in windows 10 & 11, but I wanted to deploy it in win 7. I have registerred the .dlls and reformat the app icon to the win 7 supported scale. After installing the app and run it, i got this kind of error:

> unexpected error

This error didn't explain anything right? I have tried google it, and nothing fix mine.

Comment: Without any details about the program it's impossible to say. It could simply be that it's using an API call or other properties that's not available in Windows 7. I'd suggest installing VB on the Windows 7 machine and see if the code runs in the IDE.

Comment: Define _"deployed"_. How did you "deploy" the application on Windows 10 & 11? Copy & Paste? With some kind of installation/setup, if so - which one? Have you tried creating a setup with VB6's Setup & Deployment wizard? Try that on the dev machine and inspect the setup.lst _(I think that's how it's called)_ and you might find out which component is needed on the Windows 7 machine. Possible culprits are ADO, XML and Windows Common Controls.

Comment: Win7 does not support 32-bit color deprh icons. Try reducing color depth to 24 or 8-bit one and set 32-bit one at runtime on Win8+ client OS only.

Comment: If you run your app as administrator you will likely get a more specific error. Make sure you install it with the package and deployment wizard.

Comment: I didn't use the Deployment wizard for some reason. I use the "Setup2Go" App to deploy it. I have tried to open the app with the administrator before, it's because the app need to move the db from 1 app to other. The administrator didn't give the specific error. The error was the same with the above. The win 10 & 11 icon that I used is in .gif format, then i chnage it to .ico with 24-bit.

Comment: Where does this error appear?

Comment: When I was trying to open my appllication in win7.